# Added a button in the textarea through renderer2 in a directive, but it isn't visible in the browser, though I can see it in console

Tags: angular, angular-renderer2

i am trying to add a button to a textarea dynamically through renderer2, in a directive. But the button is not visible. Below is my directive code-

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appMain]'
})
export class MainDirective {
  @Input() initial: string; inText: string;
  constructor(private el : ElementRef, private rend: Renderer2) {
    let r= this.rend.createElement('button');
    let t= this.rend.createText('Click Me!');
    this.rend.appendChild(r, t);
    this.rend.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement,r);
    this.rend.setStyle(r, 'display', 'block');
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement);  

   }
```

when I console log the nativeElement, the button is visible.[snapshot of console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBG9Y.png)

Comment: Textareas are for text (as the name suggests), not for HTML elements. If you want to "add a button to a textarea", you will have to make your CSS look like it, but your HTML can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably wanna add to the native element

```
el.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', r);
```